Smart Contract version update doubts
It is possible to update smart contracts using unstructured storage. But I have some doubts.

Would it keep the same address as the first SC?
Would it keep the persistence of the log information, or would each deployment have its own log?
Is there any simpler method that I don't know that does not use unstructured storage?

